# Copy data on one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to transfer `tbl_products` from system 1 to system 2 that means both system have same DB and same `tbl_products`.Need to get the same data in system 1's database to system 2's  `tbl_products`.

I had used COPY method in PostgreSQL to export and import data as csv.

In system 1

```
Copy (select * from tbl_products) to 'D:\AppFolder\DataTran\tbl_products).csv' with csv headers;
```

transferring `tbl_product.csv` via internet and

In system 2

```
Delete from tbl_products:
copy tbl_products from 'D:\AppFolder\DataTran\tbl_products).csv' with csv headers;
```

Now I need to implement this same method using SQL Server

**Note:  Both computer is not connected.**

Comment: If you can access both machine by any common machine, then you can write DBIS batch or export/Import by CSV as intermediate.  https://dbisweb.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use OLE Automation Object to write in csv:

```
DECLARE @Var as xml --or nvarchar(max)
SELECT @Var= --some content yoy want to write in file

DECLARE @FSO int
DECLARE @hr int
DECLARE @src varchar(255)
DECLARE @desc varchar(255)
DECLARE @oFile int
DECLARE @filename nvarchar(max)='D:\Reports\our.csv';

-- Create OLE Automation Object
EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @FSO OUT
IF @hr <> 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @FSO, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
    SELECT hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), Source=@src, Description=@desc
    RETURN
END 

-- Create the file
EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @FSO, 'CreateTextFile', @oFile OUT, @filename, 8 , True
IF @hr <> 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @FSO, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
    SELECT hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), Source=@src, Description=@desc
    RETURN
END
--Here we put content in file
EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @oFile, 'Write', NULL, @Var
IF @hr <> 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @FSO, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
    SELECT hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), Source=@src, Description=@desc
    RETURN
END

-- Clear used objects
EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @FSO
IF @hr <> 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @FSO, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
    SELECT hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), Source=@src, Description=@desc
    RETURN
END
EXEC @hr = sp_OADestroy @oFile
IF @hr <> 0
BEGIN
    EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @oFile, @src OUT, @desc OUT 
    SELECT hr=convert(varbinary(4),@hr), Source=@src, Description=@desc
        RETURN
END
```

So you just need to put all the table in `@Var`, or write a `while` loop with taking every string and putting it into file, or... whatever you want.

To load csv-data on server you can use:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
SELECT a.* FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'D:\our.csv', FORMATFILE = 'D:\our.fmt') AS a;
```

The sample of our.fmt (it's file that describes the fields in csv)

```
9.0
4
1  SQLCHAR  0  50 ";"        1  Field1                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
2  SQLCHAR  0  50 ";"        2  Field2                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
3  SQLCHAR  0  50 ";"        3  Field3                SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
4  SQLCHAR  0  500 "\r\n"      4  Field4        SQL_Latin1_General_Cp437_BIN
```

You can find description of *.fmt [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190393.aspx) .

Comment: This what I was looking for

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server, you would more likely set up a db link between the two servers (this is easy, although the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx) is rather long).

Then, you simply do:

```
select t.*
into <local_table>
from <remote_link>.<database>.<schema>.<table>;
```

There is no need to go through CSV for this purpose.

Comment: +1 for beating me by few seconds.
to @rimboche use INSERT INTO ... SELECT if your destination table already exists.

Comment: I guess you missed last line in my question

Comment: I guess you missed the first line of his answer

Comment: In addition to that... The present scenario doesn't allow a mutual connection between both computers @AnujTripathi

Comment: @Rimboche I would recommend you to use SSIS if you don't want to establish connection between the server.

Comment: @AnujTripathi and Gordon `DBLINK()` is also available in PostgreSQL but the requirement not allow  to connect both systems that's why I used COPY in PostgreSQL and looking for a similar way in SQL server

Answer (score 2):

Though, Gordon answer is valid for your question as it is one of the fastest method to copy table from one server to another. But you can also try an alternate approach to do the same. in a SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) package, you can transfer data between two server via data flow task without establishing linked server connection.

If you are new to [SSIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) than I recommend you to just use [import-export wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx) in SSMS to transfer data from one server to another. You can also generate SSIS package, in case, if it is repetitive task.
You will see below step while working on import export wizard

[image]

**TSQL solution**

You can use [OPENROWSET](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) or [OPENDATASOURCE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) to transfer data between two servers without creating any linked server. This may require your to provide username and password.

You can use it via Windows authentication

```
 SELECT *
INTO YourDbName.SchemaName.TableName
FROM    OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI', 'Data Source=RemoteServerName;Integrated Security=SSPI').RemoteDbName.RemoteSchemaName.RemoteTableName
```

or via SQL authentication

```
SELECT  *
INTO YourDbName.SchemaName.TableName
FROM    OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI', 'Data Source=RemoteServerName;user id=username;password=password).RemoteDbName.RemoteSchemaName.RemoteTableName
```

As a side note, OPENROWSET supports bulk operation.

Comment: Is there a way to do it using SQL or T-SQL, Dont want to depend this UI

Comment: @rimboche I have edited my answer with TSQL solution